# Transform encryption from JS to Python

Tags: python, encryption, sha256

I am trying to transform the following JS code to Python:

JS:

```
interval = 14400
salt = 'xuVLI!G*0RgI&B2nykYv7phzRA!N^AfI'
seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

TOTP_code = Math.floor(seconds/interval); 
raw = TOTP_code.toString() + salt

sha256digest = CryptoJS.SHA256(TOTP_code.toString() + salt);
TOTP_header = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(sha256digest);
```

but the Python code returns different values:

Python:

```
import time
import math
import hashlib

interval = 14400
salt = 'xuVLI!G*0RgI&B2nykYv7phzRA!N^AfI'
seconds = time.time() / 1000;

TOTP_code = math.floor(seconds/interval); 

raw = str(TOTP_code) + salt

raw = raw.encode('utf-8')

sha256digest = hashlib.sha256(raw).hexdigest()

print(sha256digest)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In the Python code, `time.time()` must not be divided by 1000 because `time.time()` already specifies the time in seconds (in contrast to `new Date().getTime()` which gives the time in milliseconds).

Comment: That's right Topaco, that solved the issue! Thanks a lot!